# visual studio 2010 web publish to copy static content which are not part of the solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio 2010 web publish to publish asp.net mvc 2 site. The problem I am having is that, I have static files which are not part of the solution and I would like them to be copied together with other files when I publish. Is this possible in visual studio 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add those files to the project.

Comment: Most of those files are dynamically created by the web app itself. Is it possible for the publish to copy files outside the project?

Comment: For the time being I will just go with that